# ( Alexa ) Is it possible to get the response in same Intent Handler?

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service, vui

I have a custom *Alexa Skill* similar to some *Q&A* skill , in which I'm asking the user for a response (say option_1, option_2, option_3), but when the user responds with one of these asked options a different *intent* (say *ruleIntent*) is triggered because the option text is somewhat similar to its *utterances*.

I think it is not a good design if *more than one* **IntentHandler** is triggered for same( or similar) phrase, but then I don't know the text of options in advance to avoid this (or what the user is going to speak out as the answer of asked question). What if I can somehow maintain the ***context*** of user's response, I think that will be one of the solutions.

Example : -

```
1.User : Start a Science test  {Invokes testIntent }.
2.Alexa : Okay, but before starting do you want to know the rules. Please answer in Yes or No. { response generated from testIntentHandler}
3.User : Yes { invokes many intents }
```

In line 3 even if I *hard-code* this to a Intent (say *ruleIntent*) , then what will happen if some question contains its options as **Yes** or **No**. How will I differentiate that and map that to the response of asked question.

Answer (score 0):

One way to deal with this is to track the state using persistent or session attributes.

You can do a check of the state in the canhandle method to route the user to appropriate test intent

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this could be to use Dialogs. You can use auto delegation for dialogs

> Enable auto delegation, either for the entire skill or for specific
>   intents. In this case, Alexa completes all of the dialog steps based
>   on your dialog model. Alexa sends your skill a single IntentRequest
>   when the dialog is complete

[Delegate the Dialog to Alexa](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/delegate-dialog-to-alexa.html)